# Why is application of complex transformations in manim behaving wierdly?

Tags: python, debugging, manim

The complex transformation of the line should map the line to a circle passing through the origin, also the complex transformation of the circle centered at 1,0,0 of radius 1 should map to a line but it is behaving weirdly.

```
from manim import *
#config['frame_height'] = 10.0
#config['frame_width'] = 10.0
class Method(Scene):
    def construct(self):

       text = Tex(r"Applying Complex Transformations")
       self.play(Create(text))

class Complex(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        d=ComplexPlane()
        k=d.copy()
        self.play(Create(d))
        self.add(k)
        line = Line(start=[2,0,0],end=[2,5,0],stroke_width=3,color=RED)
        circle = Circle().shift(RIGHT)
        self.add(line)
        c = Circle().shift(RIGHT)
        self.play(c.animate.apply_complex_function(lambda z:z**2)) #works correctly
        self.play(line.animate.apply_complex_function(lambda z:1/z),run_time=5) #behaving wierdly
        self.play(circle.animate.apply_complex_function(lambda z:1/z),run_time=5) #behaving wierdly
```

[applied to line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgIFY.png)

[applied to circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27viY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well the function 1/z diverges at z=0, therefore, every point that starts at that position (or near it) will have problems and give you weird artifacts. I tried your code and the line seems fine to me, but the circle is the one that might do weird stuff, and it just so happens that the circle goes through (0,0) in the complex plane. Try Shifting it some more so that it doesn't happen.

```
circle = Circle().shift(RIGHT*1.5)
```

you can also of course, change the function so that it doesn't diverge at z=0. Something like 1/(z+2) should work

Comment: Is there any way to generate a line with more number of points say 100? The reason it's behaving wierdly cause the line is made of very few points

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by weird behaviour, the line tranformation seemed fine to me. Again, the problem is not so much with the line and circle definitions, but with your chosen function 1/z.